# how to make dotted particle-like text with pure css

Tags: html, css, text

how do you make text like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCyP8.png)

sort of like particle dotted text

also pure css please without three.js

i tried adding an image of dots over text but that also didn't work

first reason being you can't hide overflow with text

second reason it didn't give the same feeling

is there any way to achieve this without three.js and without photo editing?

here is the code of what i tried

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@1,700&family=Noto+Sans+JP&family=Playfair+Display&family=Red+Hat+Display&family=Red+Hat+Text&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.aurorae {
  font-family: 'Red Hat Display', serif;
  font-size: 15vw;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aurorae span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw
}
#a1 {
  top: -5vh;
  left: -16vw;
}
.warp__0a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(9vw,0vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9775848874019741);
}

.warp__1a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(22vw,-1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9918541177811926);
}

.warp__2a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(36vw,-3vh) rotate(-0.031557rad) skewX(-0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9981059660717526);
}

.warp__3a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(48vw, -3.5vh) rotate(-0.01759rad) skewX(-0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999711960882787);
}

.warp__4a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw,-3vh) rotate(0.08315rad) skewX(0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9980067013088312);
}

.warp__5a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(77vw,-1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9904640541084487);
}

.warp__6a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(90vw,-0.5vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.975184600127323);
}
#a2 {
  top: -30vh;
  left: -18vw
}
.warp__0a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw,50vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9726552656020944);
}

.warp__1a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(24vw,49vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9800647897775718);
}

.warp__2a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw,48vh) rotate(-0.116788rad) skewX(-0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9931880294313613);
}

.warp__3a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw,47.75vh) rotate(-0.015825rad) skewX(-0.015825rad) scaleY(0.999874787300624);
}

.warp__4a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw,48vh) rotate(0.104798rad) skewX(0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9945137135068197);
}

.warp__5a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw,49vh) rotate(0.067726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9755545052568039);
}

.warp__6a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw,50vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9613238773849044);
}
#a3 {
  top: -50vh;
  left: -18vw
}
.warp__0a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw,92vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9400157002866855);
}

.warp__1a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(23vw,94vh) rotate(0.007726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9573195883848435);
}

.warp__2a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw,95vh) rotate(0.116788rad) skewX(0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9883247148311696);
}

.warp__3a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw,95.25vh) rotate(0.015825rad) skewX(0.015825rad) scaleY(0.9998639770658183);
}

.warp__4a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(65vw,95vh) rotate(-0.104798rad) skewX(-0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9877142377064163);
}

.warp__5a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw,94vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9589977165648023);
}

.warp__6a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw,93vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9405674386786304);
}
#a4 {
  top: -60vh;
  left: -20vw;
}
.warp__0a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(12vw,127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9030449674047885);
}

.warp__1a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(25vw,128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9459833520291915);
}

.warp__2a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(40vw,129vh) rotate(0.031557rad) skewX(0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9889846515502553);
}

.warp__3a4{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(52vw,129.25vh) rotate(0.01759rad) skewX(0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999856191499683);
}

.warp__4a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(67vw,129vh) rotate(-0.08315rad) skewX(-0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9903675099397263);
}

.warp__5a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(81vw,128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9488212582678166);
}

.warp__6a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(94vw,127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9164114466423967);
}

.img {
  background-image: url(dots.png);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 1%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="aurorae">
        <span id="a1">
            <span class = "warp__0a1">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a1">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a1">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a1">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a1">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a1">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a1">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a2">
            <span class = "warp__0a2">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a2">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a2">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a2">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a2">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a2">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a2">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a3">
            <span class = "warp__0a3">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a3">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a3">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a3">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a3">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a3">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a3">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a4">
        <span class = "warp__0a4">A</span>
        <span class="warp__1a4">U</span>
        <span class="warp__2a4">R</span>
        <span class="warp__3a4">O</span>
        <span class="warp__4a4">R</span>
        <span class="warp__5a4">A</span>
        <span class="warp__6a4">E</span></span>
        <div class = "img"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the image that i used

[image]

here is what i got

[image]

## AFTER BACKGROUND-CLIP

after using background-clip, it still doesn't work

this is the new code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@1,700&family=Noto+Sans+JP&family=Playfair+Display&family=Red+Hat+Display&family=Red+Hat+Text&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.aurorae {
  font-family: 'Red Hat Display', serif;
  font-size: 15vw;
  z-index: 1;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aurorae span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw
}
#a1 {
  top: -5vh;
  left: -16vw;
}
.warp__0a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(9vw,0vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9775848874019741);
}

.warp__1a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(22vw,-1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9918541177811926);
}

.warp__2a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(36vw,-3vh) rotate(-0.031557rad) skewX(-0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9981059660717526);
}

.warp__3a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(48vw, -3.5vh) rotate(-0.01759rad) skewX(-0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999711960882787);
}

.warp__4a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw,-3vh) rotate(0.08315rad) skewX(0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9980067013088312);
}

.warp__5a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(77vw,-1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9904640541084487);
}

.warp__6a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(90vw,-0.5vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.975184600127323);
}
#a2 {
  top: -30vh;
  left: -18vw
}
.warp__0a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw,50vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9726552656020944);
}

.warp__1a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(24vw,49vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9800647897775718);
}

.warp__2a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw,48vh) rotate(-0.116788rad) skewX(-0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9931880294313613);
}

.warp__3a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw,47.75vh) rotate(-0.015825rad) skewX(-0.015825rad) scaleY(0.999874787300624);
}

.warp__4a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw,48vh) rotate(0.104798rad) skewX(0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9945137135068197);
}

.warp__5a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw,49vh) rotate(0.067726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9755545052568039);
}

.warp__6a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw,50vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9613238773849044);
}
#a3 {
  top: -50vh;
  left: -18vw
}
.warp__0a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw,92vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9400157002866855);
}

.warp__1a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(23vw,94vh) rotate(0.007726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9573195883848435);
}

.warp__2a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw,95vh) rotate(0.116788rad) skewX(0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9883247148311696);
}

.warp__3a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw,95.25vh) rotate(0.015825rad) skewX(0.015825rad) scaleY(0.9998639770658183);
}

.warp__4a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(65vw,95vh) rotate(-0.104798rad) skewX(-0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9877142377064163);
}

.warp__5a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw,94vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9589977165648023);
}

.warp__6a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw,93vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9405674386786304);
}
#a4 {
  top: -60vh;
  left: -20vw;
}
.warp__0a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(12vw,127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9030449674047885);
}

.warp__1a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(25vw,128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9459833520291915);
}

.warp__2a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(40vw,129vh) rotate(0.031557rad) skewX(0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9889846515502553);
}

.warp__3a4{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(52vw,129.25vh) rotate(0.01759rad) skewX(0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999856191499683);
}

.warp__4a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(67vw,129vh) rotate(-0.08315rad) skewX(-0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9903675099397263);
}

.warp__5a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(81vw,128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9488212582678166);
}

.warp__6a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(94vw,127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9164114466423967);
}

.img {
  background-image: url(dots.png);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 1%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "img">
    <div class="aurorae">
        <span id="a1">
            <span class = "warp__0a1">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a1">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a1">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a1">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a1">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a1">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a1">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a2">
            <span class = "warp__0a2">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a2">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a2">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a2">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a2">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a2">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a2">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a3">
            <span class = "warp__0a3">A</span>
            <span class="warp__1a3">U</span>
            <span class="warp__2a3">R</span>
            <span class="warp__3a3">O</span>
            <span class="warp__4a3">R</span>
            <span class="warp__5a3">A</span>
            <span class="warp__6a3">E</span>
        </span>
        <span id="a4">
        <span class = "warp__0a4">A</span>
        <span class="warp__1a4">U</span>
        <span class="warp__2a4">R</span>
        <span class="warp__3a4">O</span>
        <span class="warp__4a4">R</span>
        <span class="warp__5a4">A</span>
        <span class="warp__6a4">E</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is what i get

[image]

the text is transparent

Comment: Basically you can't. Oh, something complicated with text clip and a fuzzy background might work but that's not cross browser supported and is an awful lot of work for something that might be better achieved with SVG.

Comment: Have you looked into background-clip ?

Comment: @AHaworth that won't clip it exactly according to the text. I will just try svg like Paulie_D said

Comment: It clips according to each character so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @AHaworth can you kindly either send me a link of the code or send it as an answer with a code snippet

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes all the options i have got are content-box, border-box, and padding-box and that just trims it in boxes. And besides my element isn't a div with a background, its an image

Comment: I can’t see any img there, only a background.

Comment: @AHaworth oh sorry my bad thought i used an img. But either way, i don't get how i could use background-clip. Please just send it as an answer with the full code so i can understand

Comment: Have a look at background-clip: text at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip and try something. If still stuck put the new code into the question with a description of what isn’t working.

Comment: @AHaworth i put the new code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get each character to clip the background you can put its background as the 'dots' rather than that background being in a separate div.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@1,700&family=Noto+Sans+JP&family=Playfair+Display&family=Red+Hat+Display&family=Red+Hat+Text&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.aurorae {
  font-family: 'Red Hat Display', serif;
  font-size: 15vw;
  z-index: 1;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aurorae span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11vw;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVGCH.png);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

#a1 {
  top: -5vh;
  left: -16vw;
}

.warp__0a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(9vw, 0vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9775848874019741);
}

.warp__1a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(22vw, -1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9918541177811926);
}

.warp__2a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(36vw, -3vh) rotate(-0.031557rad) skewX(-0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9981059660717526);
}

.warp__3a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(48vw, -3.5vh) rotate(-0.01759rad) skewX(-0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999711960882787);
}

.warp__4a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw, -3vh) rotate(0.08315rad) skewX(0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9980067013088312);
}

.warp__5a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(77vw, -1vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9904640541084487);
}

.warp__6a1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(90vw, -0.5vh) rotate(-0.027726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.975184600127323);
}

#a2 {
  top: -30vh;
  left: -18vw
}

.warp__0a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw, 50vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9726552656020944);
}

.warp__1a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(24vw, 49vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9800647897775718);
}

.warp__2a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw, 48vh) rotate(-0.116788rad) skewX(-0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9931880294313613);
}

.warp__3a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw, 47.75vh) rotate(-0.015825rad) skewX(-0.015825rad) scaleY(0.999874787300624);
}

.warp__4a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(64vw, 48vh) rotate(0.104798rad) skewX(0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9945137135068197);
}

.warp__5a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw, 49vh) rotate(0.067726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9755545052568039);
}

.warp__6a2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw, 50vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9613238773849044);
}

#a3 {
  top: -50vh;
  left: -18vw
}

.warp__0a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(10vw, 92vh) rotate(0.057726rad) skewX(0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9400157002866855);
}

.warp__1a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(23vw, 94vh) rotate(0.007726rad) skewX(-0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9573195883848435);
}

.warp__2a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(38vw, 95vh) rotate(0.116788rad) skewX(0.116788rad) scaleY(0.9883247148311696);
}

.warp__3a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(50vw, 95.25vh) rotate(0.015825rad) skewX(0.015825rad) scaleY(0.9998639770658183);
}

.warp__4a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(65vw, 95vh) rotate(-0.104798rad) skewX(-0.104798rad) scaleY(0.9877142377064163);
}

.warp__5a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(78vw, 94vh) rotate(-0.067726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9589977165648023);
}

.warp__6a3 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(92vw, 93vh) rotate(-0.057726rad) skewX(-0.057726rad) scaleY(0.9405674386786304);
}

#a4 {
  top: -60vh;
  left: -20vw;
}

.warp__0a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(12vw, 127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9030449674047885);
}

.warp__1a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(25vw, 128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9459833520291915);
}

.warp__2a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(40vw, 129vh) rotate(0.031557rad) skewX(0.061557rad) scaleY(0.9889846515502553);
}

.warp__3a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(52vw, 129.25vh) rotate(0.01759rad) skewX(0.00759rad) scaleY(0.9999856191499683);
}

.warp__4a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(67vw, 129vh) rotate(-0.08315rad) skewX(-0.06315rad) scaleY(0.9903675099397263);
}

.warp__5a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(81vw, 128vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9488212582678166);
}

.warp__6a4 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(94vw, 127vh) rotate(0.027726rad) skewX(0.027726rad) scaleY(0.9164114466423967);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="aurorae"><span id="a1"><span class="warp__0a1">A</span><span class="warp__1a1">U</span><span class="warp__2a1">R</span><span class="warp__3a1">O</span><span class="warp__4a1">R</span><span class="warp__5a1">A</span><span class="warp__6a1">E</span></span>
    <span id="a2"><span class="warp__0a2">A</span><span class="warp__1a2">U</span><span class="warp__2a2">R</span><span class="warp__3a2">O</span><span class="warp__4a2">R</span><span class="warp__5a2">A</span><span class="warp__6a2">E</span></span>
    <span
      id="a3"><span class="warp__0a3">A</span>
      <span class="warp__1a3">U</span><span class="warp__2a3">R</span><span class="warp__3a3">O</span><span class="warp__4a3">R</span><span class="warp__5a3">A</span><span class="warp__6a3">E</span></span><span id="a4"><span class="warp__0a4">A</span>
      <span
        class="warp__1a4">U</span>
        <span class="warp__2a4">R</span><span class="warp__3a4">O</span><span class="warp__4a4">R</span><span class="warp__5a4">A</span><span class="warp__6a4">E</span></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! This helped me out!